# raises a response from the validator in the form of json data in laravel

Tags: json, laravel, object, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a controller that generates json, how do I get an error message from the validator if the error message also becomes json,

```
$this->validate($request,[
        'product_type' => 'required',
        'product_name' => 'required|string',
        'qty' => 'required',
    ]);
 -- code for saving process here --

 return response()->json([
            'status' => 'success',
            'msg'  => 'data succesfuly added'
        ]);
```

and this my return in network preview

```
errors: {product_type: ["The Product Type name field is required."], product_name: ["The address field is required."],…}
product_name: ["The product_name field is required."]
0: "The address field is required."
qty: ["The qty field is required."]
0: "The qty field is required."
```

i try with ajax but is did'nt work

```
success: function(response) {
                Object.keys(response.errors)
                            .forEach(function eachKey(key) {
                            createAlert(response.errors[key], "danger");
                            });            
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'product_type' => 'required',
        'product_name' => 'required|string',
        'qty' => 'required',
]);
if ($validator->fails()) {

    //pass validator errors as errors object for ajax response
     return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
}
```

You can use `$validator->messages()` or `$validator->errors()` that returns an `array` which contains all the information about the `validator`, including errors. The `json` function takes the `array` and encodes it as a `json` string.

So on client side you can get errors object by:

```js
$.ajax().done(function(response){
    //check if response has errors object
    if(response.errors){

    // do what you want with errors, 

    }
});
```

Comment: hay karan, why i found error
"message": "Class 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Vendor\\Validator' not found",

Comment: ADD `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;` OR `use Validator;`